# How to make register notification in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, ios9.1

I have an online radio. The radio has programs at different times, programs are displayed in a list.
My need is that when one tap and hold on the list of program he schedule a notification to the User.

examplo program in list:

[image]

Tap and hold is already running (code below):

```
-(void)registerHour:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint ponto = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:ponto];

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.imageAgendamento.hidden = false;

        NSString *test = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hour" ]];
        NSLog(@"hour -> %@", test);
    }
}
```

> The test is where has the time of notification "09:00" (in direct
>   format JSON)

appDelegate.m i add:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

}
```

Looked at several tutorials and researched in various places, I could not solve my problem any way. What I need to do to get this notification schedule?

Comment: you can try local notifications.

Comment: look at this http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: ok, I'll see if I can using this tutorial

Comment: where is ur code to register notification

Comment: try local notification , in the u can set the fire time.

Comment: I updated the post. It was best to understand my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a 5 min delayed local notification using the code below:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
[dateComponents setMinute:5];
NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:currentDate options:0];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// Configure the notification
// ....
//

localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

But I think what you need to do is using an `NSTimer` or simply the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method of `NSObject`.

Comment: Yes, add it into your function, or wherever you need to schedule the notification.